# Read from URL & Process data using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, urllib

I am new to python and I am trying to read data from URL. Basically I am reading the historical stock data, get the closing price and save the closing price in to a list. The closing price is available at the 4th index (5th column) of each line. And I want to do all of these within a list comprehension.

Code snippet:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

URL = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=3&b=1&c=2016&d=9&e=30&f=2016"

def downloadClosingPrice():
    urlHandler = urlopen(URL)
    next(urlHandler)
    return [float(line.split(",")[4]) for line in urlHandler.read().decode("utf8").splitlines() if line]

closingPriceList = downloadClosingPrice()
```

The above code just works fine. I am able to read and fetch the required data. However just out of curiosity, can the code for list comprehension be written in a more simpler or easier way ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I did try out various ways and this is how I could do the same using different forms of list comprehension:

```
return [float(line.decode("utf8").split(",")[4]) for line in urlHandler if line]
#     return [float(line.decode("utf8").split(",")[4]) for line in urlHandler.readlines() if line]
#     return [float(line.split(",")[4]) for line in urlHandler.read().decode("utf8").splitlines() if line]
```

The first one is better because it reads the file line by line which saves memory. And of course it's simpler and easier to understand.